# page is not directed properly in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using multiple role using laravel.I am following a link https://dev.to/kaperskyguru/multiple-role-based-authentication-in-laravel-30pc.But when i register on my laravel website. it says "This page is not working.localhost directed you too many times.
my route is:

```
route::get('/student','studentController@index')->name('student')->middleware('student');
route::get('/teacher','teacherController@index')->name('teacher')->middleware('teacher');
```

Student middleware file:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
        if (Auth::user()->role == "STUDENT") {
            return redirect()->route('student');
        }
        if (Auth::user()->role == "TEACHER") {
            return redirect()->route('teacher');
        }
        // return $next($request);
    }
```

LoginController:

```
protected $redirectTo ;

    public function redirectTo()
    {
            if(Auth::user()->role =="STUDENT")
            {
                $this->redirectTo = '/student';
                return $this->redirectTo;
            }
            if(Auth::user()->role=="TEACHER")
            {
                $this->redirectTo = '/teacher';
                return $this->redirectTo;
            }
    }
```

RegisterController:

```
protected $redirectTo;

    public function redirectTo()
    {
            if(Auth::user()->role =="STUDENT")
            {
                $this->redirectTo = '/student';
                return $this->redirectTo;
            }
            // if(Auth::user()->role=="TEACHER")
            else
            {
                $this->redirectTo = '/teacher';
                return $this->redirectTo;
            }
    }
```

Comment: what exactly do you want this middleware to do? you want it to stop users who are not students from getting to the route the middleware is on? it is hard to tell what you are actually trying to accomplish with this middleware

Comment: I have a teacherMiddleware just like student. I wanna stop students to get access of the teacher side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middleware should have a logical path that lets the Request continue through the stack to its destination. All you have are redirects being returned. You have this middleware assigned to the route that the middleware wants to redirect to as well, which will cause an infinite loop. You probably want to make some adjustments:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        // no authenticated user
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    if (Auth::user()->role != strtoupper($role)) {
        // they don't have the role we are checking
        // redirect them away to some default location
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    // allow the Request to continue to the destination
    return $next($request);
}
```

Add this middleware to your HTTP Kernel as 'roleCheck', or what ever you like. Then you can assign this middleware to a route as `roleCheck:student` or `roleCheck:teacher`.

```
Route::get('/student','studentController@index')
    ->name('student')
    ->middleware('roleCheck:student');

Route::get('/teacher','teacherController@index')
    ->name('teacher')
    ->middleware('roleCheck:teacher');
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by a infinite redirection loop.

You should check your route configuration, I think you have protect (via middleware) also the "login" route. You should leave that routes open for every kind of user.

Comment: Can you specify your solution please.Actually I am new to laravel :/

Comment: Ohh..I am really sorry. I didn't see that.